# HTTParty post method doesn't return status code when adding follow_redirects = false along with other headers and cookies?

Tags: ruby, https, http-headers, httparty, http-status-code-302

The HTTParty methods are like   `HTTParty.XXX(urlGoesHere, and Args Here)`

I'm doing the following:

```
params = {:UserName => "uname", :Password => "pwd"}

cookie_hash = HTTParty::CookieHash.new
cookie_hash.add_cookies("key1=val1")
cookie_hash.add_cookies("key2=val2")

options = {
   :body=>params,
   :headers => { 'Cookie' => cookie_hash.to_cookie_string,
                 'Accept' => something },
   :follow_redirects => false
}

URLUserNamePwd = HTTParty.post(myURL, options) # Is this the right way to do?
```

When I check the http status code, body I get nothing. When I check in the browser development console, I see 302 redirect, and in response headers I see lot of header pairs returned.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL you're attempting to hit? [302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) Found will be paired with a  `Location` header containing the URL where the resource can be found.